# Latest click getting processed with exhaustMap instead of first one

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to make request only for the first click and ignore all other subsequent click while the first request is still ongoing. And for that i used exhaustMap operator. But it seems to be working like switchMap as all the initial requests are getting cancelled and only the latest one is getting processed.

[image]

Here is the code

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Accept: "application/json" });
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.sUrl}/token`, null, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        exhaustMap((token: any) => {
          oRequest.token = token.token;
          headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
          return this.http
            .post(`${this.sUrl}/find`, oRequest, { headers: headers })
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
        })
      );
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're creating the same chain on every click. If you want to use `exhaustMap`, you'll need to have just one chain that is subscribed and push events to it using a Subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example with fake API: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-kyq38b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { mergeMap, exhaustMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">submit</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  submit$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.submit$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.http.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/`)),
        exhaustMap(film =>
          this.http.get(film["characters"][0].replace("http", "https"))
        )
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.submit$.next(true);
  }
}
```

You click 'Submit' and all proceeding click events will be ignored by exhaustMap() operator until HttpClient instance returns response and get completed.